# registered user retrieving in firebase chat app

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am developing a chat app same as whatsapp but I am getting problem in fetching users who had registered my app and who is in contact list ...

**My Database:**

```
 chat
   users
     -TnBhKlDUWhZZtnXjqJPwybCXs043
       name:prem jangir
       phone:+9180947729xx;
       avatar:htpp://...
     -TjjfdldlvllUdffkgjfkkfkkgkfk
     .
     .
```

**My Code:**

```
    ArrayList<Contacts> allContact = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    RecyclerView allUserRecycle;
    ArrayList<Users> allUsers =new ArrayList<>();
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_users);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

      while (i <= allContact.size()-1) {
                Contacts contact = allContact.get(i);
                String phone = contact.phone;
                retrieveUsers(phone);
                i++;
            }
    }

public void retrieveUsers(String phone ) {
        Query mQuery=mDatabase.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(phone).limitToFirst(1);

        if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()!=null)
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
        assert mQuery != null;
        mQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

               Users u= dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                if(u!=null)
                    Log.e("test",u.name);
                allUsers.add(u);
            }
```

I have already retrieved all the contact from contact list and stored in allContact `ArrayList`.
 this code take much time to show the data in recycleview....
is it right way to do or there is any other way to do it properly 
kindly help

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you need to remove this lines of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
```

You don't need to go offline and then go online. This will slow down the speed of showing your data in the RecycleView. When you are creatine a new `FirebaseDatabase` reference, you are already connected. So, there is no need to use those methods.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code is fine. Is now an improve of your speed?